# Serilog does not write files after installing the service with sc.exe

Tags: windows, asp.net-core, .net-core, service, serilog

I have developed a net core 3.1 service for windows, the service works fine, but fails to write the log file.
during debugging Serilog writes the file correctly, but once installed with sc it writes nothing.

Program.cs

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseWindowsService()
                .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfig) =>
                loggerConfig.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)) // custom log event
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    IConfiguration configuration = hostContext.Configuration;           //prendi la configurazione

                    ServiceInfo siOption = configuration.GetSection("ServiceInfo").Get<ServiceInfo>();

                    services.AddSingleton(siOption);

                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                });
    }
```

appsettngs.json

```
 "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Override": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "(@Level = 'Error' or @Level = 'Fatal' or @Level = 'Warning')"
                }
              }
            ],
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "path": "Logs/ex_.log",
                  "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp} [{Level:u3}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                  //"outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:o} [{Level:u3}] ({SourceContext}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                  "rollingInterval": "Day",
                  "retainedFileCountLimit": 7
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [
      "FromLogContext",
      "WithMachineName"
    ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "ORAMS-II Service Status Telegram"
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know what the problem could be, installed on a linux machine writes the file correctly

Comment: serilog writes files using the normal file APIs - you can debug/troubleshoot this by considering file locations and permissions only. The Serilog `SelfLog` (search it) might be reporting some exceptions internally.